# How to have make this visualization in d3.js using values from a column matching a specific string

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I am trying to implement the following problem while learning d3.js for visualization.

Using the following titanic dataset:

1. Plot in scatterplot :

a)the male passengers using an SVG square (width 5, x and y - 2.5 )

b)the female passengers using a circle of radius 2.8

c) Have the survived column used as opacity such that the dead have opacity 0.25 and alive have opacity: 1;
fill-opacity:.1;
stroke: black;

2. Make the scatterplot axes, make the y axis to log scale, and add the passengers name on their mark (using the SVG title element).

I am implementing the following code to achieve my goals but, I have am not successful in displaying my graph.

Can anyone please help me.

The titanic dataset - [here](https://gist.github.com/michhar/2dfd2de0d4f8727f873422c5d959fff5)

And my code here:

```js
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//Read the data
d3.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/michhar/2dfd2de0d4f8727f873422c5d959fff5/raw/fa71405126017e6a37bea592440b4bee94bf7b9e/titanic.csv", function(rawData) {
  const data = rawData.map(function(d) {
    return {
      age: Number(d.age),
      fare: Number(d.fare),
      sex: d.sex,
      survived: d.survived === "1",
      name: d.name
    };
  });

  // Add X axis
  var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 80])
    .range([0, width]);
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");

  // Add Y axis
  var y = d3.scaleLog()
    .domain([1e+0, 1e+3])
    .range([height, 0]);
  svg.append("g");

  // Add dots

  svg.append('g')
    .selectAll("dot").select("female")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return x(d.age);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return y(d.fare);
    })
    //.attr("r", 2.8)
    .style("opacity", function(d) {
      return d.survived ? "1" : "0.25";
    })
    .style("stroke", "black")
    .style("fill-opacity", 0.1)

  svg.append('g')
    .selectAll("dot").select("male")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return x(d.age);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return y(d.fare);
    })
    //.attr("width", 5)
    .style("opacity", function(d) {
      return d.survived ? "1" : "0.25";
    })
    .style("stroke", "black")
    .style("fill-opacity", 0.1)
    .append("svg:title")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name
    });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>
```

can anyone please highlight where i am making mistake and help me please

Comment: Don't just post your code here, check to see if it works!

Comment: Don't ask questions with multiple questions in one, it discourages people from answering if they know answers to only a few of the parts, and will thus be less helpful to you. Google first before just writing a question like this, or use StackOverflows search engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really, really need to read the manual, especially the SVG one. [`rect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/rect) nodes don't have `cx` and `cy`, they have `x` and `y`, `width`, and `height`. And [`circle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/circle) needs a radius `r` in order to be visible.

And you gave all the properties you read a lowercase starting letter. They need capitals. Look up a manual on debugging.

```js
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//Read the data
d3.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/michhar/2dfd2de0d4f8727f873422c5d959fff5/raw/fa71405126017e6a37bea592440b4bee94bf7b9e/titanic.csv", function(rawData) {
  const data = rawData.map(function(d) {
    return {
      age: Number(d.Age),
      fare: Number(d.Fare),
      sex: d.Sex,
      survived: d.Survived === "1",
      name: d.Name
    };
  });

  // Add X axis
  var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 80])
    .range([0, width]);
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");

  // Add Y axis
  var y = d3.scaleLog()
    .domain([1e+0, 1e+3])
    .range([height, 0]);
  svg.append("g");

  // Add dots

  svg.append('g')
    .selectAll("dot").select("female")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return x(d.age);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return y(d.fare);
    })
    .attr("r", 2.8)
    .style("opacity", function(d) {
      return d.survived ? "1" : "0.25";
    })
    .style("stroke", "black")
    .style("fill-opacity", 0.1)

  svg.append('g')
    .selectAll("dot").select("male")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return x(d.age);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(d.fare);
    })
    .attr("width", 5)
    .attr("height", 5)
    .style("opacity", function(d) {
      return d.survived ? "1" : "0.25";
    })
    .style("stroke", "black")
    .style("fill-opacity", 0.1)
    .append("svg:title")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name
    });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks not only for the answers but also for the explanations you have left. It really helps

Comment: However, can i request you if possible to share some good reading materials in javascript and d3.js in particular, please. It will be really really helpful

Comment: Normally, I would share some articles for specific things, but for you, I just don't know where your level is. Just google "d3js getting started" for the most basic tutorials